# Can you exclude child pages of a specific parent within a navigation?

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages, children

For example, I'm using wp_list_pages to display the navigation, the child pages (and their children) appearing on hover as is typical. However, I want one of these parents to *not* display the children. Essentially I want something like exclude_children_of to work in the wp_list_pages arguments; is there a way of doing this anybody?

thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try -:

if your page ID = 999

```
<?php
$child_ids = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_parent = 999  AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page' AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.ID ASC");
$exclude = implode($child_ids,', ');
wp_list_pages('exclude=' . $exclude . '&title_li=<h2>' . __('Pages') . '</h2>');
?>
```

Comment: you are most welcome.